# Integrate narayana transaction manager with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jboss, transactions, jta

My standalone application already uses narayana transaction manager for JTA transaction with other XA resources and now I am trying to integrate it with Hiberante also. So that hibernate transactions also executes under JTA transcation scope-

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
 <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">
  org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>

<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">
   <!-- org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup -->com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionManagerImple
</property>

<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
```

other java conf -

```
registry.applySetting(AvailableSettings.JTA_PLATFORM,     "org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossStandAloneJtaPlatform");

registry.applySetting(AvailableSettings.TRANSACTION_COORDINATOR_STRATEGY,     "jta");
```

and here is how I am starting the transaction-

```
TransactionManager transactionManager     =com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager.transactionManager();
transactionManager.begin();

Session session = currentSessionContext.currentSession();

session.joinTransaction();
System.out.println("is joined "+session.isJoinedToTransaction());

session.update(obj);
transactionManager.commit();
session.close();
sessionFactory.close();
```

Now problem is that db is showing the changes of session only after call to sessionFactory.close() 
but shouldn't it be at transactionManager.commit() .

How can I configure it to make db update after transactionManager.commit() ?

Answer (score 0):

You're close. What's missing is JDBC connection enlistment with transaction manager, see https://jbossts.blogspot.com/2017/12/narayana-jdbc-transactional-driver.html.

This extra step is necessary, because Narayana implements the JTA specification, and JTA works with XAResources not with JDBC connections. Some glue code is required to a) provide XAResource for JDBC connection b) enlist that resource to transaction